# Error while running client code in EJB

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, noclassdeffounderror

Getting error while running client code in EJB:

> Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/kernel/KernelStatus  at
>   weblogic.jndi.Environment.(Environment.java:78)   at
>   weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:197)   at
>   User.main(User.java:21)

I added `wlfullclient.jar`, server's Remote interface jar, also I saw article in which I saw to add `wlclient.jar` and `weblogic.jar` but then also got same error.

Help highly appreciated.

Client code:

```
import com.amdocs.Stateful.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class User 
{
public static void main(String args[]){
Hashtable<String,String> ht = new Hashtable<String,String>();

ht.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");// you have to start from root location to search for JNDI tree
//JNDI registry tree is normally maintained as Binary tree, JNDi is normally binary tree which have root node at top

ht.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001"); // address of registry
try{
    System.out.println("Hello");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(ht); // start searching wrt what we set in ht , it's constructor takes HashTable only

    System.out.println("Hello2");
    MyCartRemote ref=(MyCartRemote)ic.lookup("MyCartBeanJNDI#com.amdocs.Stateful.MyCartRemote");
    ref.add("Hi");
    ref.add("Jeetendra");

    MyCartRemote ref1=(MyCartRemote)ic.lookup("MyCartBeanJNDI#com.amdocs.Stateful.MyCartRemote");
    ref1.add("Hi");
    ref1.add("Subhash");
    ref1.add("Ghai");

    System.out.println("Object 1 data: "+ref.show());
    System.out.println("Object 2 data: "+ref1.show());
}
catch (NamingException e){      e.printStackTrace();    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing  WebLogic System Libraries from the Bootstrap Entries section.  It worked for me when i got the same error.

Comment: Also we need to add  wlclient.jar file located here \wlserver_10.3\server\lib to the User Entries section in the classpath.