# Hibernate DataSource using JNDI + Weblogic

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I am trying to connect to my database using a Java `DataSource`. I am using Weblogic 12c and Hibernate to achieve this. My `web.xml` file contains the following resource definition:

```
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Microtek</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

In addition, my `weblogic.xml` contains the following:

```
    <wls:resource-description>
        <wls:res-ref-name>jdbc/Microtek</wls:res-ref-name>
        <wls:jndi-name>microtek</wls:jndi-name>
    </wls:resource-description>
```

In my Hibernate config file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`), I have set the  following properties:

```
      <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/Microtek</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
```

Also, inside the `META-INF` directory, I created an XML file called `context.xml` which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/Microtek" name="jdbc/Microtek" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

Finally, this is the exception I have been getting:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2827)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1838)
    at com.microtekcomputers.models.test.main(test.java:15)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
    ... 8 more
```

It is my first time using JNDI to connect to a data source so I might be missing something. All ideas & recommendations greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** After making the changes suggested by others, I am now getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/kernel/KernelStatus
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:81)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2827)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1838)
    at com.microtekcomputers.models.Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a connection factory defined for your data source, something like this in the code:

```
environment.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
```

Or this in the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="jndi.class">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</property>
```

In weblogic you can configure connection factories to your need, WLInitialContextFactory is the default.

Also see the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24391/weblogic/jndi/WLInitialContextFactory.html) and [client examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT369)

Comment: I added the property to the hibernate file and I am getting the error above

Comment: Did you get past this? Try removing WebLogic System Libraries from the Bootstrap Entries section. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639876/error-while-running-client-code-in-ejb

Comment: I actually decided not to do it using JNDI because of time constraints but I will later on try it again and let you know if it works. Thanks for the help